# How to create https self hosted webservice without using certificate in Windows using C#/.Net

Tags: web-services, wcf, https, certificate

Here is some context:
We need to create a self hosted web service on windows machine without having to have any additional application server software like IIS. 
We cannot use certificate as there is a risk in having the certificate's private key be compromised.
Is it really possible to create a https service without certificate in Windows certificate manager?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to create a WCF service over Https without a certificate.
Https protocol requires us to bind a certificate to the machine port since https consists of Http protocol and SSL certificate. Besides, the IIS web server is not necessary, we could host the service in a Windows NT service/console application.
Here is an example of hosting a WCF service over HTTP in windows service.
[C# windows service - expose web interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932401/c-sharp-windows-service-expose-web-interface/54940911#54940911)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.